# JSON Object array inside array find and replace in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I have one JSON Object like this :

```
var myObject = [    
{
    "Name" : "app1",
    "id" : "1",
    "groups" : [
        { "id" : "test1", 
          "name" : "test group 1", 
          "desc" : "this is a test group"
         },
        { "id" : "test2",
          "name" : "test group 2",
          "desc" : "this is another test group"
         }
    ]
},
{
    "Name" : "app2",
    "id" : "2",
    "groups" : [
        { "id" : "test3", 
          "name" : "test group 4", 
          "desc" : "this is a test group"
         },
        { "id" : "test4",
          "name" : "test group 4",
          "desc" : "this is another test group"
         }
    ]
},
 {
    "Name" : "app3",
    "id" : "3",
    "groups" : [
        { "id" : "test5", 
          "name" : "test group 5", 
          "desc" : "this is a test group"
         },
        { "id" : "test6",
          "name" : "test group 6",
          "desc" : "this is another test group"
         }
    ]
}

];
```

I have new value available of "name" for specific "id".
How can I replace "name" of specific "id" inside any object ?

And how to count total number of groups among all objects ?

for example : replace name to "test grp45" for id = "test1"

Here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/qLTB7/21/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: It's not a JSON object, it is just a javacsript object.

Comment: Yes. My mistake !. It's JS object. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @zerkms— *myObject * is an Array (which, granted, is a particular kind of Object). ;-)

Comment: In the outer object you have "Name", the inner objects you have "name", is that how it should be?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following function will search through an object and all of its child objects/arrays, and replace the key with the new value. It will apply globally, so it won't stop after the first replacement. Uncomment the commented line to make it that way.

```
function findAndReplace(object, value, replacevalue) {
  for (var x in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
      if (typeof object[x] == 'object') {
        findAndReplace(object[x], value, replacevalue);
      }
      if (object[x] == value) { 
        object["name"] = replacevalue;
        // break; // uncomment to stop after first replacement
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qLTB7/28/

Comment: Instead of *break* you could use *return* to make it more obvious that it stops there. Also, `typeof object[x] == typeof {}` is very inefficient (it creates a new object every time), use `typeof object[x] == 'object'`. Also should include a *hasOwnProperty* test, you don't want to check inherited enumerable properties.

Comment: @RobG - I wrote this up real quickly. I will add those changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function findAndReplace(object,keyvalue, name) {
    object.map(function (a) {
        if (a.groups[0].id == keyvalue) {
            a.groups[0].name = name
        }
    })
}

findAndReplace(myObject,"test1" ,"test grp45");
```

Comment: Thanks Manjesh. PitaJ suggested exactly same. Worked !

Answer (score 1):

**Maybe a more succinct sol'n**

```
function changeName(objArray, objId, newName) {
    objArray.forEach(function(obj) {
        if (obj.id === objId) obj.Name = newName;
    });
}
```

**Personally**: if this were me, when creating these objects, I would create a new obj and key them by id.

```
 var myApps = {};
 myObject.forEach(function(o) {
     myApps[o.id] = o;
 });

=>
{
    "1": {
        "Name": "app1",
        "id": "1",
        "groups": [
            {
                "id": "test1",
                "name": "test group 1",
                "desc": "this is a test group"
            },
            {
                "id": "test2",
                "name": "test group 2",
                "desc": "this is another test group"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**And then you could just do:**

```
myApps['someId'].name = 'This is my new Name'
```

[Check it out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/qLTB7/40/](http://jsfiddle.net/qLTB7/40/)

Comment: Hi Todd..Thank you for feedback..we can directly do the same with Object[0] , Object[1] right ?

Comment: That only works for objects in the first array, it doesn't recurse into the objects in the *groups* array. It also continues looping, even after a match has been found.

Comment: @vkaiz yes, we could do that in an iterative way, as you're describing. I thought you were just looking for a way to select an object by its ID, then change the name property.

Comment: @RobG, thanks for pointing out that the loop isn't broken until ALL objs are checked. On a different note, I didn't understand that "deep" name changing was needed.

Comment: @Todd—the OP says "How can I replace "name" of specific "id" inside ***any*** object", so I assumed it could be at any level. I might be wrong, only the OP knows. :-)

Comment: @RobG, I appreciate your attention to detail. Continue making SO a better place!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach using [*Array.prototype.some*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.17). It assumes that the *Name* property in the outer objects should be actually be *name* (note capitalisation).

```
function updateNameById(obj, id, value) {
  Object.keys(obj).some(function(key) {
    if (obj[key].id == id) {
      obj[key].name = value;
      return true;  // Stops looping
    }
      // Recurse over lower objects
      else if (obj[key].groups) {
      return updateNameById(obj[key].groups, id, value);
    }
  })
}
```

The advantage of *some* is that it stops as soon as the callback returns true.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:-

```
var id = 'test1';
var newname = 'test grp45';
var numberOfGruops = 0;
myObject.forEach(function(app){
numberOfGruops += app.groups.length;    //Count all groups in this app
app.groups.forEach(function(group){
    if(group.id===id)
        group.name = newname;   // replace the name
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be **if (object["id"] == value)** instead of **if (object[x] == value)** in 7th line of PitaJ answer, so whole function will look like:

```js
function findAndReplace(object, value, replacevalue) {
  for (var x in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
      if (typeof object[x] == 'object') {
        findAndReplace(object[x], value, replacevalue);
      }
      if (object["id"] == value) { 
        object["name"] = replacevalue;
        // break; // uncomment to stop after first replacement
      }
    }
  }
}
```

if you leave object[x] - function will replace name also for objects with other keys values set to "test1", for example
{"id": "xxx", "name": "test group 1", **"desc": "test1"**}